# how to capture a UE4 scene and stream it into a virtual camera device

Tags: unreal-engine4

I want to make the scene of Unreal Engine 4 into virtual camera device so that I can live broadcast it directly.

An alternative could be to use a screen capture tool to capture the scene window and make it a virtual camera device. The first way is more friendly to our users.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

My solution in the end: using FRunnable and directShow for it.
A runnable captures the framebuffer, directShow sends it to webcam.
The SceneCapture2D solution works, it just doesn't perform well.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it from within unreal is to use a `SceneCapture2D` actor within your scene that then renders to a render target texture and then export that somehow.

However this captures the scene every tick and it is really not performance friendly.

If you wish to do live broadcasts I suggest using a 3rd party software.